# Safari stretching header and images

Tags: html, css, wordpress, safari

This project will be the death of me. I'm making a website in wordpress with my own custom theme. The address is www.codykrauskopf.com seems to work correctly on ios(safari),wp8.1(ie),ie(desktop),chrome(desktop) and firefox(desktop). However, safari on desktop stretches the header and the image in the header vertically down the left side of the page. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
 <img src="http://codykrauskopf.com/images/logo.png" width="100%" height="100%" alt="Circus Logo">
```

You set `width="100%"` and `height="100%"`. This is **not relative to the image**, but instead **relative to the container**. For windows safari, it seems to be relative to the document.

Just remove the width/height values, or set them to the image dimensions.

```
 <img src="http://codykrauskopf.com/images/logo.png" alt="Circus Logo">
```

By the way, Windows Safari hasn't been updated in a long time, and may even be dead. The mac version is still receiving updates, though.

Comment: I think the width and height 100% were inserted by wordpress. I can't seem to find anywhere I personally set the width and height to 100%. However, if Safari is dead on windows then I don't really care. I had a friend check it on Mac and it looks fine.